# advantage to programming with oop for SQL queries

Tags: mysql, oop, zend-framework, yii

I've been getting acquainted with the Zend and Yii frameworks and am trying to understand the benefits of using some of their built-in methods to perform MYSQL queries.  While I definitely see the benefits of using their classes to connect to the database, and to do things such as insert/update, I'm trying to understand the benefit of using objects for SELECTing from the database, as it seems to just obscure the MYSQL statement when the queries are complicated.  Is there any benefit, or is it just a matter of preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, i'm not a Zend or even a PhP developer, but I would say that your already pointed out the biggest advantage : "obscuring" the SQL; That way you're not tight with 1 specific DBMS. For example, you don't select a range the same way in mysql and sql server. So let's suppose you switch from the one to the other, if you're not using the framework objects for doing your queries, you may need to rewrite it.
If you use the framework, you'll probably only have to switch database connectors (or whatever they're called in the framework).

Comment: OK!  That makes total sense.